# Error preloading the connection pool

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat7, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I am using below env:

- jdk1.6.0_21
- apache-tomcat-7.0.16
- commons-dbcp.jar (version: 1.2.2)
- commons-pool.jar (version: 1.3)
- MySql Server 5.1

Facing below exception all the time when trying to connect with DB:

```
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Error preloading the connection pool
```

Please help.

Comment: Which settings (and values) do you have for your connection pool?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza

DbInitialSize - 50, 
DbMaxActive - 25,
DbMaxIdle - 25,
DbMaxWait - 1000

Comment: Change all of them to 10 and try again.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza
great!!! seems my problem fixed, but want to know the reason. why this was happening ? any ways thanks a lot ...

Comment: most likely the max number of connections you configured is too high for the pool. A number 32 comes to my mind, but I am not sure

Answer (score -6, accepted):

As suggested by @Luiggi Mendoza in above comments:

Change all DB property (describe below) value to **10** :

- DbInitialSize
- DbMaxActive
- DbMaxIdle
- DbMaxWait